# While uploading large files getting error

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, upload, size

I am using .net 4.5. I set maximum request length and `maxAllowedContentLength` in config file as 100 mb. When I try to upload larger than 100 mb file (like 200mb to 1000mb) I am getting an error

```
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that exceeds the request content length
```

This is normal and expected error but when I try to larger than 1 gb, I am  getting error "internet explorer cannot display page".

I think it is due to a timeout issue but I really can't figure out actual reason of this error.

Thank u.

Comment: Look at this answer, is for download, but take a look of it and focus on the session lock http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600856/how-to-deliver-big-files-in-asp-net-response/9601866#9601866

Answer (score 2):

This has been asked about on StackOverflow many times.  I'll continue the tradition :)  For large uploads you need to set two parameters:

- ***maxAllowedContentLength*** is **measured in bytes**, so make sure you've actually set it correctly.  To allow 1GB uploads, it should be 134217728.
- You also need to configure ***maxRequestLength*** as well as maxAllowedContentLength.  Note though that it is **measured in kilobytes**, so it will be different.

For example:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>

<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear, but what I think you're running into is IIS's normal behavior reguarding exceptions: any issue with the request returns a 500 server error response.

In oder to view exceptions you can either disable this behavior in the configuration file ([MSDN Link](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors)), or transfer the file while logged into the server (connections from `localhost` bypass this behavior by default).