# Request Too Large

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis-7.5

I am receiving the following error on my page, I updated the IIS setting for posting limit, but can't find how to increase the work buffer size, any help on this would be awesome

```
Request Too Large
The "POST" request is too large for the internal work buffer:

    The internal work buffer size is 512 bytes.
    The "POST" request size is 2313 bytes. 

Return to last page
```

Official status error from firebug: **413 Request Entity Too Large** 
I am using IIS7.5 for setting up the page

The site is built via .NET MVC4

and I can not reduce the post size, in fact in some cases it only increase.

Comment: does anything here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9600856/how-to-deliver-big-files-in-asp-net-response help?

Comment: Not really the post is done via a backend service, I am only the consumer. and can't seem to find anything where the 512 bytes are referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer, you have to update the UploadReadAheadSize in IIS the article here showed me how to do it from IIS.

http://tips4sysadmins.blogspot.com/2012/12/iis-75-uploadreadaheadsize.html

> How to set the uploadReadAheadSize in IIS 7.5
>
> - Launch "Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager"
>
>   - Expand the Server field
>   - Expand Sites
>   - Select the site you want to make the modification for.
>   - In the Features section, double click "Configuration Editor"
>   - Under "Section" select: system.webServer>serverRuntime
>   - Modify the "uploadReadAheadSize" section
>   - Click Apply
>
> *Note that the value is in BYTES*