# Large Dataset Download to excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel, epplus

I am using EPPlus to download large excel file. when I see the file it writes the data into it but while downloading it says timeout expired error! 
I do have the following piece of code.

```
     dtExport.Rows.Add(drFooter);
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     ds.Tables.Add(dtExport);
        try
        {
            FileInfo template = new FileInfo(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"\ExcelPackageTemplate.xlsx"));
            FileInfo newfile = new FileInfo((filePath + filename));

            var rowCount = dtExport.Rows.Count;
            using (ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newfile, template))
            {
                /**************Create Worksheet with datatable-- No Formatting************/
                ExcelWorkbook wb = pck.Workbook;
                ExcelWorksheet sheet = wb.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
                sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dtExport, true);

                string[] columnTypes = new string[dtExport.Columns.Count];

                for (int i = 0, j = 1; i <= dtExport.Columns.Count - 1; i++, j++)
                {
                    if (dtExport.Columns[i].ColumnName == "Date")
                    {
                        sheet.Column(j).Width = 12;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sheet.Column(j).AutoFit();
                    }
                }

                pck.Save();

                pck.Dispose();
              }
            }
          Response.TransmitFile((Server.MapPath("Excel/Rpt" + fileName)));

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: the one I tried returns almost 127269 rows but it can contain larger than this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the AsyncPostBackTimeout="600" in updatepanel and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the executionTimeout might address the timeout issue that you are running into by default the timeout is set to 110 seconds. You can find more information regarding this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9601866/981) and [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/aghausman/archive/2009/02/20/prevent-request-timeout-in-asp-net.aspx).

**Update 1:**

I'm finding indications that possibly calling Response.Flush(); after Response.TransmitFile might help but I'm still trying to sort out the reasoning for this. I will follow up if I find a good reason.

**Update 2:**

According to the MSDN documentation Response.TrasmitFile does not buffer meaning that Response.Flush should have no effect on its processing.

**Update 3:**

I dug trough the source code for EPPlus and they have some sample code for handling downloads with ASP.NET [here](http://epplus.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/c7f28bd90c59#EPPlusWebSample/GetSample.aspx.cs)

```
Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;  filename=Sample3.xlsx");
```

Comment: I presume that you'll have to change the content type and disposition to match.