# How do I transmit a large, multi-gig file in ServiceStack?

Tags: c#, asp.net, servicestack

I'm using ServiceStack as my web framework and am trying to send a 3 gig file across the pipe.  Below is the code I'm trying to use to send the file.  It works for small files, but when I try to send large files the application stalls and never actually sends the files.

```
    public IHttpResult Any(TilesRequest request)
    {
        var filename = request.Name.ToLower();
        var filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(ConfigLookups.TilesDirectory + filename);
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + filename);
            var stream = File.OpenRead(filePath);
            return new HttpResult(stream, "application/x-sqlite3");
        }
        else
        {
            return new HttpError(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "File not found");
        }
    }
```

I also tried doing:

```
Response.TransmitFile(filePath);
```

but then I get an error that says:

> The size parameter must be between zero and the maximum Int32 value.

Any ideas on how I should properly be sending such a large file?

Answer (score 3):

`Response.TransmitFile` in ServiceStack just delegates to ASP.NET's [TransmitFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12s31dhy(v=vs.110).aspx) which is the API for efficiently sending large files - it uses an efficient Win32 API underneath which from the error description, looks like it's limited to 2 GB (2^32) in size. It's not clear if this is limitation is lifted in a 64bit OS.

Other limitations are imposed by ASP.NET (i.e. ServiceStack doesn't add any limitations itself). This previous thread shows a few tips you can try to [send large files with ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9600856/85785).

This also applies to ServiceStack since it's just a wrapper around ASP.NET's `IHttpHandler`. You can get the underlying ASP.NET Response with:

```
var aspResponse = base.Response.OriginalResponse as HttpResponseBase;
```

The built-in ASP.NET httpRuntime request limits would also need adjusting.

You also want to disable buffering to avoid the built-in 2^32 size limit. ASP.NET does this by default when compression is enabled so you also want to disable this:

```
<system.webServer>
   <urlCompression doStaticCompression="true" doDynamicCompression="false" />
</system.webServer>
```

But generally if you exceed the 2^32 limit you're likely going to have issues trying to sending this much data at once in ASP.NET no matter what you do.

### Partial Content Responses

The solution I'd be looking at for streaming large files instead is to use ServiceStack's built-in [Partial Content Support](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Service-return-types#partial-content-support). Which instead of streaming a large file in 1 request, change the HttpClient to fetch the file in chunks over multiple requests.

#### A Physical File

```
return new HttpResult(new FileInfo(filePath), request.MimeType);
```

#### A Memory Stream

```
return new HttpResult(ms, "audio/mpeg");
```

Here are some examples of using [HttpUtils](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Http-Utils) to fetch [Partial Content from ServiceStack Services](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/PartialContentResultTests.cs#L126), e.g:

```
var url = "{0}/{1}".Fmt(BaseUrl, new TilesRequest { ... }.ToUrl());
var partialBytes = url.GetBytesFromUrl(
    requestFilter: httpReq => httpReq.AddRange(Offset, ChunkSize),
    responseFilter: httpRes => {
        "Content-Length header {0}".Print(
           httpRes.Headers["Content-Length"]);
    });
```

You would need to do this in a loop to stitch up all the partial byte responses together.