# Page with garbled text appears when any unhandled error occurs

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-5, aspnetboilerplate

Whenever an unhandled error occurs, I get following screen instead of yellow screen.

[image: suckr]

Please note I have enabled Localization in ASP.NET Boilerplate and current language/culture is set to en-US.

For some pages, the language text values are stored in AbpLanguageTexts table.

Comment: If you are using aspnet core, try https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.1#configure-status-code-pages

Comment: @ryan: I am not using asp.net core

Comment: @NitinSawant That's a [template](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Templates). Which options did you select?

Comment: MVC 5.x => Multi Page Web application

Answer (score 1):

This is happens when the page is send back with **gZip** compression but with **wrong Content-Length**.

The result are the non-correct decompress of the data.

The solution is to **remove** the Content-Length or remove **the compression** from the error page/message.

You can also check this similar answer : 
[HTTP Compression: Some external scripts/CSS not decompressing properly some of the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210526/http-compression-some-external-scripts-css-not-decompressing-properly-some-of-t/3210574#3210574)