# Page displays random symbols instead of error message on Firefox

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, gzip

Randomly, on a few projects, some pages display random symbols instead of an error message. Like this one :

��������`I�%&/m�{J�J��t��`$@�����iG#)�*��eVe]f@�흼 ��{���{��;�N'���?\fdl��J�ɞ!���?~|?"��Ey�')=��y6����h�����Ųi��- �ez����7i޴i�L���,�4�̧i���Ίe��Ͼ|uz����:�}�*��U{���������΋��~�ȗu.-�����l>F'�����Y�l��$k�tF����*��{�� ��[����'U���|6J�lR��b6��юG�k�^,ӏ��߿�}<~<�;c�R鱕iV��m�|��� �yDl���tRͮ�*|N��>�Ey�裟�k*��!z���Ѳ�Y)5��G��A�8$D��Ѥ̦oI��]�P �"�/��v[����W�~���m`N�rvk���Mqz3���wV�

It happens quite randomly, and seems to be caused by different factors. Here, it's on a file upload.

We use SharpZipLib on this page, but the codepath shouldn't use it.

Does anyone knows why this happens, and how to prevent it ?

**EDIT :** it only happens on Firefox. IE(8) displays the error message correctly.

**EDIT 2 :** it seems to happen quite randomly, only on some pages/sites. The same page on another IIS site works well. It seems to do this only on IIS7 ; I have no reports of those on IIS6, and I haven't encountered it on my dev machine.

**EDIT 3 :** it looks like it happens only when the page crashes.

**EDIT 4 :** Ok, so, it happens only on IIS7, and only when I get an error 500. I think it might be the IIS error pages that have a problem. How can I try to change them ?

Firebug gives me those headers :

*Response*
Cache-Control   private
Content-Type    text/html; charset=utf-8
Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-AspNet-Version    2.0.50727
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
Date    Mon, 04 Apr 2011 10:31:24 GMT
Content-Length  2284
*Request*
Host    xxxx
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; fr; rv:1.9.2.16) Gecko/20110319 Firefox/3.6.16 ( .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET4.0E)
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset  ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive  115
Connection  keep-alive
Referer xxxxx
Cookie  xxxxxx

Is there any way for me to say "on this page, I don't accept gzip compression at all" ?

Comment: Possibly you are specifying a strange encoding for the page?  One that doesn't match the actual encoding you are using?  Alternatively - somehow your application is spewing out raw binary data into the response stream... but that should be easy to track down.

Comment: I do not set any encoding on this page. I am using SharpZipLib on this page, but it shouldn't be used in this case.

Comment: And it's not that easy to track down, because it only happens on the production server, not on my dev machine.

Comment: It shows the error message on IE but not Firefox...

Comment: Added more details on my findings

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I did not find any real solution, but I found a satisfying workaround.

Keep in mind that the problem only arises under those conditions :

- The website is configured on IIS7 / Windows Server 2008.
- The page displaying the garbage symbols has, in reality, crashed. The resulting "garbage" is, in fact, an gzip-compressed error message that has not been decompressed, or something like that.
- Disabling gzip compression on either dynamic or static content does'nt change anything

The workaround is simple : refuse gzip-compressed content in the browser. In Firefox, as seen in http://forgetmenotes.blogspot.com/2009/05/how-to-disable-gzip-compression-in.html :

1. Type about:config in the URL bar (Accept the disclaimer)
2. Type encoding in the filter field underneath the URL bar
3. Doubleclick the line "network.http.accept-encoding"
4. Empty the value

On my website, it did some weird things with the CSS (and StackOverflow does not have any CSS at all after that), but at least it correctly showed me the error message, which enabled me to fix the bug.

Hopefully it will help someone.

Answer (score 8):

Another workaround for anyone stumbling across this could be to remove the response filter on application error, which will get rid of the encoding and send it through uncompressed. Since this is only for error messages the impact on performance should be minimal.

In your Global.asax

VB

```
Sub Application_Error()
    Response.Filter = Nothing
End Sub
```

C# (I assume this is right, see blog link below)

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Filter = null;
}
```

All credit to Rick Strahl with [this blog post](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/02/ASPNET-GZip-Encoding-Caveats) for the workaround.

Note: I also added this an an answer to my own question here - [IISExpress garbled HTTP 500 error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23407530/iisexpress-garbled-http-500-error-message/27122972#27122972)

Comment: save my day.Thanks

Answer (score 4):

**This is looks like gZip error decoding.**

Check if you set the Content-Length in a way on your pages, and then use gZip filter. If yes then remove the Content-Length set from your code.

This can happend when you send the Content-Length and later you compress it and iis can not change the header Content-Length to the new compressed one, and send the wrong size, then browser is reading the wrong size  and fail to decompress it correct.

reference:
[ASP.NET site sometimes freezing up and/or showing odd text at top of the page while loading, on load balanced servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582139/asp-net-site-sometimes-freezing-up-and-or-showing-odd-text-at-top-of-the-page-whi/2719080#2719080)

### Update

Other possible reason is to set a wronge **Response.ContentType**, for example to set it as text and you send a gif image, or to set it as image and you send a text.

### Update 2

Maybe the error is on the the content type. Set this headers:

```
context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + cFileNameToShowAndDownload);
```

Comment: I do not use content-length anywhere on this page. I will try without dynamic content gzip compression.

Comment: Yep, deactivating gzip compression on IIS doesn't change a thing. Maybe I'm doing it wrong, I'm not used to IIS7.

Comment: @cosmo0 You maybe set the content length anywhere on any module that called from your site. Also the gzip some times happens from code inside the site. Check the header on your pages to see if content length is set. Check if you gzip it here http://www.pipeboost.com/report.asp

Comment: Nope, a search for "content-length" on the whole solution doesn't returns any result.

Comment: @cosmo0 Then maybe is not the content-length the error, but you need to follow a different approche. I will update my answer.

Comment: Well, it's not for generating a file, it's just to write html ! Do you suggest I forcibly set the content-type to text/html ?

Comment: @cosmo0 if its not for zip, and you see this chars that are zipped one, then the error is on zipping/unziping ->gzip. Find how you make the gZip and double check it out. When you make gZip, if you make it 2 times in a row then is a problem, for example you make gzip on web ? The gZip is the problem here.

Comment: Do you know how I could force the header "accept-encoding" to "disable" gzip ? I think it might be because raw text is sent, that the browser tries to decompress anyway, thinking it's gzip. I just found a method that reproduces the bug (I think it's when an error message is returned). Thanks !

Comment: @cosmo0 You can remove it from, but if the zip is happens on iis, then you simple need to stop that. To remove it from header you also need to setup the iis. Search on google for how to remove a header.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue with dotnet core. (This question is closing in on 9 years old right now. Don't think this will help op, but maybe other people will find this helpful).

I was getting similar garbled text, it looked like gzip encoding. Disabling compression in firefox like the selected answer seemed to verify this. The problem only showed up when trying to render a partial view with a script block with non-standard content (kendo template). It wasn't anything related to when an exception was occurring or not.

The problem came down to configuration. We were using a 3rd party library that was breaking the response. Using compression as Microsoft outlines at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-2.2 fixed the problem (we stopped using the 3rd party lib). As mentioned on https://stackoverflow.com/a/54372810/1462295 , the ordering matters when configuring the compression and static file setup.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
    {
        options.Providers.Add<BrotliCompressionProvider>();
        options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    // ordering matters here
    app.UseResponseCompression();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also "fix" this in Chrome (or Brave) with the `ModHeader` extension. Then just add a `Request header` with the name `Accept-encoding` and value of nothing and reload your page:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a little late, but I think it can help someone.

In my case, the problem was that I was using session state in a SQL Server database.  Because I had moved the ASPState database to another server, the credentials in the web.config file were not up to date. Correcting this, fixed the problem.