# MVC View Display Nonsense Data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, gzip

Recently I came across an issue with an Index view.  The page displays as nonsense data as seen in this image link, [Result of UserManager.Users.ToListAsync()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZn2U.png). This just start happening but not sure why.  Any help on this would be amazing!

The code is pretty simple:

```
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    return View(await UserManager.Users.ToListAsync());
}
```

The View

```
@model IEnumerable<SafeWare.Models.Identity.ApplicationUser>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>

</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
        </th>
        <th>

        </th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.Id }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }

</table>
```

OnActionExecuting

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    bool allowCompression = true;
    //bool.TryParse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Compression"], out allowCompression);

    if (allowCompression)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        string acceptEncoding = request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding)) return;

        acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToUpperInvariant();

        HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

        if (acceptEncoding.Contains("GZIP"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
            response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
        else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("DEFLATE"))
        {
            response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
            response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
        }
    }
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}
```

Comment: Looks like an text encoding issue. What does your view look like?

Comment: Yeah, this happens when you try to stuff double byte characters into an ASCII string.

Comment: Thanks guys, I've added the view code. It's pretty plain Jane vanilla view code

Comment: Might also be that you have set up Gzip compression but aren't using the correct HTTP headers. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3960707/215552 or http://stackoverflow.com/q/5876930/215552 for instance.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan ah yes! That could be it.  I'll look into that. I've added my OnActionExecuting

Comment: I would think my whole application would be failing though. This is from a BaseController that executes the OnActionExecuting