# Set web config debug to false and broke project

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, web, web-config

We have a website that we have almost finished turning into an application.  Everything works fine except a little issue with BrowserLink in IE 8 and IE 7.  So I found somewhere that told me to change debug to false.  So I did.

```
<!--<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">-->
  <compilation debug="false">
```

Unfortunately when I did that, this is what the login page looked like.
[image]

If anyone has any ideas of what could be causing this that would be awesome.  I know that this is EXTREMELY general, but I don't really know what is causing the problem...Everything works fine when debug="true". And please don't tell me WHY it should be set to false, I have already read enough articles talking about that.

Comment: Have you tried including the targetFramework when debug is set to false?

Comment: Yeah, I am thinking it might have something to do with compression.  Because that looks like what is going on.  But I am not sure why it would compress when it was out of debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the charset of the `web.config` open with any text editor u will see the which encode is there like:

- ANSI
- ISO
- UTF-8

select the UTF-8 it may fix the issue

Comment: The web.config is set to Utf  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: you may refer this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143536/page-displays-random-symbols-instead-of-error-message-on-firefox , if already checked this then u need to re-look your codes or post them here.

Comment: Yeah it was the GZIP encoding. We had the masterpage forcing GZIP when it was out of debug.