# How can i get error message on browser instead of complex characters like pic

Tags: asp.net, runtime-error

[image]

Why are error messages like the picture above. How can i get error messages that can i understand.
asp.net web site .net 4.5.2

Comment: Probably an encoding error - nobody can help you unless you show the relevant part of your code. Is it happening for all pages? If so, show us header from master page, etc.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate question. Please look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4143536/page-displays-random-symbols-instead-of-error-message-on-firefox

Comment: @RyanTernier i searched but never find. i couldn't find which words to search.  Should i delete the post now

Comment: Are you using GZIP in iiS?

Comment: @RyanTernier, yes i use.

Comment: Look at the link I posted. Turn your GZip off in your IIS that will help you with the error messages.

Comment: Thanks for your help @RyanTernier