# ASP.Net - Random encoded error on screen

Tags: asp.net

I'm not even sure what to title this question, but has anyone ever seen and fixed the error in the image below?[image: Error]

This is occurring in our website and nothing is logged in IIS about the error. We're using .Net 4 on IIS 7

Comment: What kind of file were you trying to serve when this happens?

Comment: it looks like its trying to output a binary file... what's the url it's referencing?  you checked app pools, mime types, etc?  you could get more info from chrome > developer tools > network

Comment: This was occurring on a regular post back of the page (no response header/content type changes)

Comment: Wrong mimetype ? Gzipped content being served without the appropiate header ? If this should be an ASP .NET page, is the code being hit if you set a breakpoint in the debugger ? You need to provide more details to your question.

Comment: Look at it via fiddler or Developer Tools in Chrome. It seems to me that the web server is streaming a binary file without the content-disposition header.

Comment: Is it possible this is the result of an XSS attack?  Someone put some garbled javascript in a database field, and it's messing up the output, or worse, streaming data from a remote server using AJAX?  You might be able to glean more info using Fiddler.  http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Comment: Thanks for the tips guys, I'll take a look and see what I can find. Sadly, this is happening on a client's production system (not dev or anything or ours) so it's difficult to troubleshoot and get any more information.

Answer (score 0):

To give an answer, and try to help to move on, this is something that can happens if you set the  **Content-Length** on the Header and later GZip the page, but failing to change the **Content-Length** on the page (because is all ready have been written to it. And this create a failure to the browser when is try to decompress the page.

So check if you set it somewhere.

This is two similar question with the same output.

[IIS content-type wrong for compressed CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134017/iis-content-type-wrong-for-compressed-css)

[ASP.NET site sometimes freezing up and/or showing odd text at top of the page while loading, on load balanced servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582139/asp-net-site-sometimes-freezing-up-and-or-showing-odd-text-at-top-of-the-page-wh)